# Problemas com Nodejs no Linux

Tags: node.js, linux

estou com um problema, já tentei de várias maneiras e nada.

Estou fazendo um curso de JS, e em uma das aulas o professor utilizou a biblioteca Math... só que meu resultado é sempre NaN. Então pesquisando eu descobri que isso é uma espécie problema de dependência do Linux.

Desinstalei o Nodejs e o Editor Visual Studio Code do meu PC, e reinstalei e nada...

O script era:

> const raio = 5.6
>
> const area = Math.Pi * Math.pow(raio, 2)
>
> console.log(area)

Resultado:

> NaN

Comment: O "PI" de `Math.PI` é tudo maiúsculo

Comment: Isso não se trata de sintaxe. É apenas o nome da variável. :)

Comment: A linguagem é caso sensitiva, ela faz diferenciação entre maiúsculas e minúsculas, então tenha em mente que `Math.PI` é diferente de `Math.pI` que é diferente de `Math.Pi` que por sua vez é um campo diferente `de Math.pi` e documentação javascript é bem clara ao declarar que o nome do campo é [Math.PI](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/PI).

Answer (score 1):

O problema está ocorrendo por conta de erro de sintaxe (código digitado de forma incorreta)

O `PI` do `Math.PI` é escrito com letras maiúsculas

Fica dessa forma

```
const area = Math.PI * Math.pow(raio, 2)
```